# Linear transformation and direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

When given $T:V \to V$ such that $T^2=I$, prove that $U,W \subseteq V$ subspaces exist such that:

$$V=U\oplus W$$

$$T(u)=u, \forall u \in U$$

$$T(w)=-w, \forall w \in W$$

My first thought was to define $W=kerT$ and $U=ImT$, then I can prove that $\dim(U+W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W) = \dim(V)$. that shows $U \oplus W=V$, and also $T(-w)=w=\bar{0}$.

But the second condition is not met.
I was also trying to define $U=sp\{\bar{u_1},....,\bar{u_n}\}\subseteq V$  as a subspace but I can't prove that $T(u)=u$

The problem should be solved with knowledge about direct sums and linear transformation.

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: $T^2=1$ means $T^2-1=(T-1)(T+1)=0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am just a student take carefully my solution and I hope it is correct.
I think that there is a more elegant way than a prove by contradiction to prove (2). (btw i hope too that i ve understood correctly your question).

1 - *Prove that $U$ and $W$ are in direct sum.*
$U=\left \{ u \in V: T(u)=u \right \}$ and $W=\left \{ w \in V: T(w)=-w \right \}$.
It cames that any $v' \in U \cap W $ has to verify: $T(v')=v'$ as $v' \in U$ and in the same time $T(v')=-v'$ as $v' \in W$.
Moreover by definition of application the same input always give the same output so we have: $v'=T(v')=-v' \Rightarrow v'=0_V$ is the unique solution. Hence: $U \cap W = 0_V \Rightarrow U\oplus W$

2 - *Prove that $V=U+W$.*
By absurd we suppose $\exists v' \in V\setminus \left \{ U + W \right \}$.
Now let's note $T(v')=v'' \neq \pm v' \Rightarrow T(T(v')) = T(v'') = v' \neq \pm v''$. In this case it cames that: $(v'+v'')/2 \in U$ and $(v'-v'')/2 \in W$. So by definition as the sum of one element in $U$ and one element in $W$ we get: $(v'+v'')/2+(v'-v'')/2=v' \in U+W$  contradiction.

(1) & (2) $\Rightarrow$ Q.E.D.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question altogether, but your solution makes sense and seems correct. Thank you

Comment: @Staltus With pleasure

Comment: @X0-user-0X There is a problem in part 2). Suppose by contradiction that $V \neq U+W$ then there exists $v' \in V \setminus (U \cup W)$. This is not correct ! The $U \cup W$ should be $U +W$. You might want to double check if this impacts the rest of your proof.

Comment: @Digitallis thank for your remark it was a typo error, i ve corrected it and added precision (tell me if this is correct).

Comment: @X0-user-0X On second thought, I'm not sure that $T(T(v)) \neq T(v) \neq v \Rightarrow T(T(v)) \neq v$. Can you clarify?

Comment: @X0-user-0X The line : Now because $T(v'') \neq -v''$ and $T(v') \neq -v' $ we have $$  T(v') -T(v'') \neq -v' + v''.$$ is problematic. It looks like your saying something like  $a\neq b$ and $c \neq d$ implies $ a + c \neq  b  + d$. But this isn't true. See for example $-1 \neq 0$ and $1 \neq 0$ implies $0 \neq 0$.

Comment: @Staltus i ve made it more clear

Comment: @Digitallis I am agree i ve made it clearer

Answer (score 3):

We need to prove that $U \cap  W = \{0\}$ and that $ U + W = V$.

The first is easy to solve. Suppose that $v \in U \cap W$ then we have $T(v) = v$ and $T(v) = -v$ so $v$ must be equal to $0$.

For the second part let $z \in V$. Then

$$ \frac{z + T(z)}{2}\in U$$
$$ \frac{z - T(z)}{2}\in W.$$

since $T^2 = I$. It follows that

$$ \underbrace{\frac{z + T(z)}{2} + \frac{z - T(z)}{2}}_{ = z} \in  U + W.$$

Hence $V \subset U + W$ which proves $V = U + W$.

---

> In that question we are working over some field F. I guess it is not causing problems, I just wonder what meaning $\frac{1}{2}$ have when we are working over some abstract field.

If $V$ is a vector space over a field $ F$ then we can multiply vectors $v$ by scalars $\lambda \in F$. When we write
$$ v + v = 2v$$
then the number $2$ is not necessarily the number $2 \in \mathbb N$. Denote by $1_F$ the neutral element for multiplication in the field $F$. Then

$$ v + v = 1_Fv + 1_Fv =(1_F + 1_F )v $$

so when we write $2$ we actually mean $1_F + 1_F$. In particular $\frac{1}{2}$ denotes the multiplicative inverse of $2$ in the field $F$. But can we be sure that $2$ is actually invertible in $F$ ? Recalling the properties of a field you know that $\lambda \in F$ is invertible if and only if $\lambda \neq 0_F$. So as long as you are working in field $F$ such that $2 \neq 0_F$ then the above proof is valid. That is, as long as $1_F + 1_F \neq 0_F$ you wont have a problem.

It might be surprising but there actually exists fields $F$ such that $1 + 1 = 0$. For example the finite field $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: I think that there is a typo error it is $U \cap W = 0_V $ to prove that the two sub spaces are in direct sum (not $U \cap W = \varnothing $ ).

Comment: @Digitallis I just want to make sure. Is there any meaning to writing $\frac{z+T(z)}{2}$ when we are not in the context of $\mathbb{R}$? Because $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{R}$.
Thank to for the answer btw

Comment: @X0-user-0X Whoops ! Fixed it now.

Comment: This does not cause problems unless you are working over a field of characteristic $2$. If your are just starting to learn linear algebra I guess this is not the case. Do you know what field you are working over ? That is,  do you know field over which the vector space $V$ is defined ?

Comment: @Digitallis In that question we are working over some field $\mathbb{F}$. I guess it is not causing problems, I just wonder what meaning $\frac{1}{2}$ have when we are working over some abstract field. I didn't learn what "characteristic 2" is, so I guess you are right, but perhaps there is a simple explanation for why doesn't it cause any problem. If not, I'll guess I have to wait patiently

Comment: @Staltus See my  edit for an explanation.

Comment: @Digitallis Great explanation, now everything is clear. Thank you